# Using break in a for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested, break

If I use break to get out of a for loop, will it continue to read the rest of the present iteration or jump straight to the end and exit? ie.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{

break;
std::cout << "Will I be output?";

}
```

Comment: Just realised I could answer this question quicker myself! Turns out it goes straight to the end of the loop and doesn't output..

Answer (score 1):

It will not execute anything that follows  `break` statement.

In general a piece of advice would be to always execute such code and try to see if it gives you an expected result or not.

Though it is not a good programming practice it saves a lot of hassle in simple situations like this.

Comment: It is good programming practice! Testing is always good.

Comment: @AlanStokes: What I meant was that running a program just to see if it works is not a good practice. (especially when dealing with large scale projects)

Comment: Surely the only reason you would run a program before it's finished is to see if it works?

Comment: @Chrysm_Seal: Let me explain myself. It is a bad habit to test code by executing it. It may lead to errors that could be avoided by thinking the code out. Anyways this is what I have read from somewhere (most probably Code Complete).

Answer (score 1):

Calling break will exit the loop and not print.  You should also be aware of the continue statement which skips to the end of the loop and starts the next iteration.  In this code the string not print when x is 3.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; ++x)
{

    if( x == 3 )
    {
        continue;
    }

    std::cout << "Will I be output? " << x;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the cout statement becomes unreachable.